# ksoap2: Post a soap request according to this request XML

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

My soap request looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Authenticator xmlns="http://www.namespacename.com/services/">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </Authenticator>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ListItems xmlns="http://www.namespacename.com/services/">
      <strCode>string</strCode>
    </ListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm at least successfully able to login using ksoap2 but I haven't figured out about the body part, any ideas how to call ListItems with parameter strCode, like it shows above.

Here's the current code.

```
     String NAMESPACE = "http://www.namespace.com/services/";
     String METHOD_NAME = "ListItems";
     String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.namespace.com/services/ListItems";
     String URL = "https://www.kupong.se/Services/CouponAPI18.asmx";

     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
              // Enable the below property if consuming .Net service
      envelope.dotNet = true;
      envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

      envelope.headerOut = new Element[1];
      envelope.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader();

      HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
          try 
          {
              androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, null);
              response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

function for preparing header values for authentication

```
private Element buildAuthHeader() {
            Element h = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "Authenticator");

            Element username = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "UserName");
            username.addChild(Node.TEXT, username);
            h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, username);
            Element pass = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "Password");
            pass.addChild(Node.TEXT, "password)
            h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, pass);

            return h;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just looking for a way to post body message.

All you need is to create a SoapObject and pass it to bodyOut property of envelope.

```
      SoapObject sub = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
      sub.addProperty("strCode", value);
      envelope.bodyOut = sub;
```

Comment: can you please check and help to solve my que? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670782/android-call-soap-webservice-getting-message-of-server-was-unable-to-process-re?noredirect=1#comment57087199_34670782

Answer (score 0):

try the following code in AsyncTask of DoInBackground Function:

```
     String user=empidedt.getText().toString().trim();
                   String pass=passedt.getText().toString().trim();

                  System.out.println("user :"+user);
                  System.out.println("pass :"+pass);
                try{

                   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE1, METHOD_NAME1);                      
                   request.addProperty("UserId",""+user);
                   request.addProperty("Password", ""+pass);

                   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                   envelope.dotNet=true;
                   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL1);

                   androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

                   Object result= envelope.getResponse();

                   SoapObject response=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

                  strRes = result.toString();
                  System.out.println("strRes :"+strRes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Useraname and password has to be under Authenticator element and that part is already working. The part which isn't working is the function in Body with parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Ksoap2 library and write .net web service 
Sucessful Connection with Asp.net Webservice-----
package ProductVerificationCard.in;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AdminLogin extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button btn_ok;
    TextView textView;
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Login";

    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "Login";

    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2/new/WebService.asmx";
    String s;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn_ok=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_error);

        btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                        OPERATION_NAME);

                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;

                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

                        try

                        {

                        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                        Object response = envelope.getResponse();

                        //textView.setText(response.toString());
                         s=response.toString();
                         if(s=="true")
                         {
                             Intent intent=new Intent(AdminLogin.this,MenuForm.class);
                                startActivity(intent);

                         }

                         else
                         {
                             textView.setText("Enter Valid Username or Password");
                         }
                        }

                        catch (Exception exception)

                        {

                        textView.setText(exception.toString());

                        }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
        });

    }
}
```